# Web accessibility and document downloads

Tags: accessibility, compatibility, document, user-experience

Is there such a thing as being standards compliant when it comes to offering document downloads via a website?

Am I correct in thinking that some users may experience issues if I offer **only** PDFs?

For best practice should I offer all the documents as;

- PDF
- MS Word
- HTML
- all of the above

Note: Some of the documents are forms (i.e users must download, sign and return via post), so I may not be able to convert these to HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s a **usability** problem if you offer documents that your users can’t open.

It’s an **accessibility** problem if you offer documents that your users can’t access because of their disabilities (or because their assistive technologies don’t support it).

Offering *only* PDFs can be perfectly fine

- if your users have PDF readers, and
- if you make the PDF documents accessible.

(The same goes for any other document file format.)

Which formats your users are able to open can’t be answered in general, of course. If you don’t know this for your user base: the safest bet is to use HTML (obviously) and other formats typically supported by web browsers (e.g., PDF, plain text).

Offering the documents in multiple formats can of course be beneficial for your users (some users prefer certain formats/programs because of performance/features/experience/etc.), and it decreases the chance that users can’t open it, but then you should make sure that all of the provided options are accessible (or clearly mark which ones are/aren’t).

Answer (score 1):

As unor said, PDF files are fine if they're tagged PDF (look up pdf/ua or iso 14289).  A tagged pdf has extra metadata in the document that adds semantic information to the text.  If you have acrobat, you can view the tags.  They look like html with tags such as `<h1>, <table>, <p>`, etc.

If you save a word doc as pdf, word will add the tagging information.

If your user is on a locked down system (eg, if they're using a computer at the library or a hotel business center), they might not be able to install the adobe reader or ms office to read pdf or word docs.  HTML would be the only option.  Even if you have forms, you can still print a webpage with forms and they can fill it in with pen (or fill in the form fields before printing).